# Two-sample test for deviation from zero?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What would be an appropriate statistical test to test whether one sample is more significantly spread out around zero than other?

I believe that what I am looking for is a kind of f-test but instead of comparing variances (variations around the mean of each sample) I would want to compare "variances" around a fixed predefined value (in my case zero) between the two samples.

Here's a pic in an attempt to depict qualitatively how the test I seek should work:

[image]

Comment: Why are you interested in zero?

Comment: I am interest in allelic expression. And I would like to be able to test if two samples (homozygous and heterozygous) have expression values sufficiently different from zero (in log-scale, that is). So I would like to be able to detect if the spread from zero of heterozygous samples is greater than that of the homozygous samples.

Comment: Can you post an example dataset to clarify your situation?

Comment: @gung: Just added a pic which I hope clarifies what I am looking for.

Comment: What would you guys say about using Mann–Whitney U test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) on samples A' and B', where A' and B' are absolute-value-transformed samples of A and B, respectively?

Comment: Look for tests of equal variances. In your question you state variance from 0, but then your hypothesis is comparing two data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the Mann–Whitney U test on the absolute values.

Here's some code in R that does the job:

```
stat.test <- function(sample_A, sample_B, difference = 0) {
  sample_A_abs <- abs(sample_A)
  sample_B_abs <- abs(sample_B)

  wilcox.test(x = sample_B_abs, y = sample_A_abs,
              alternative = "greater", mu = difference)

}
```